# Quetzalcoatl 7-12

Tags: board-games

I have seen some tough puzzles that you have solved. I am hoping that this puzzle will not be hard.

Here are the rules:

> 1. All colored segments of a chain must be on the same color square to solve the puzzle.
> 2. You can only pull a chain into an empty space or in a closed loop with itself, but cannot be pulled through a chain or outside the boundaries of the puzzle (i.e. that red one can be looped endlessly, but that doesn't change the puzzle).
> 3. Chains can be pulled by their rounded ends, and not by their middles.

[image]

This is the picture of the puzzle as it starts out.

I already know the solution, so don't give me the solution. I want how you got to the solution, because even knowing the solution does not help much.

HINT:

> the BLUE one needs to be in a figure 8, not coiled up. To get to a figure 8, it needs to enter a spot where there is a non-colored block immediately next to it, and also on a row of 5.

Comment: I remember this level, I just wish I still had the app; this would be so much easier

Comment: It may be familiar, and it may not be, but one things for sure: YOU WILL WANT THE APP.

Comment: It saved my progress!!

Comment: Argh... These types of puzzles were in Machinarium... Absolutely horrific..

Comment: It's alot more complex than I remembered :(

Comment: Snakes/Chains are really the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take (Hope I didn't screwed any rules)

> [image]

Update-

Looks like its already solved by many with videos. One such is [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D7UYfIW2AYgA&ved=0ahUKEwi5oZOx4aLQAhULu48KHa66D_8QyCkIGzAA&usg=AFQjCNFqFvDcvZjPcWfl9vr0YLUiiv9SJg&sig2=SMpYLJDogmUJOIotQfZMsw) and a complete walkthrough [here](https://youtu.be/CkEN8-k-Yx4). Leaves this puzzle as duplicate.

Comment: If that golden step is the last one, the blue doesn't line up with the background. Also I thought it was OK to post puzzles from other sources as long as you credited them, even if there are answers to the puzzle online.

Comment: Not sure if there any many other ways to solve it. I thought it was a self created puzzle. Turns out its just a level from a game.

Comment: It's still a puzzle and it is OK to post puzzles from other sources, so I think it belongs here

Comment: Never said it doesn't belongs.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were referring to the puzzle as a duplicate

Comment: Yes. Its a duplicate and is already solved. But can belong here. I have my +1 to the question already.

Comment: That makes much more sense, I misjudged what you meant my duplicate, sorry about that

Comment: Its okay. Never mind

Comment: I know the solution: the BLUE one needs to be in a figure 8. Unfortunately, NO, it is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

So, this is not as rigorous as Techidot's solution by any means, and it's probably pretty similar, I still haven't quite figured out how to move the blue chain into it's figure 8 shape, but here's what I did. I'm posting this mostly because the way I thought about the 'steps' was different than Techidot's.

> First you "connect" the end of the green chain to the start of the yellow, and then 'connect' the end of the yellow chain to the start of the blue. What I mean here is that whenever you move the green chain forward into an empty space, the yellow must follow into the empty space now taken up by the end of the green chain.
>
> So the first step is to move the green chain until the 'front' of the chain is in the sixth column of the second row. Your board should look like this:

After step 1:

> [image]

Next:

> You can now 'disconnect' the chains, since most are where they need to be. This allows us to move forward using any number of connected chains. I'm trying now to figure out something where you use only the blue red and yellow chains and leave the green one still, but I'll post it when I get something that works. There might be one where the yellow stays still too. I'm not sure yet.

Comment: The end solution is the same as the person before you. NOT CORRECT.

Comment: @GarrisonPendergrass I said this was a partial solution, I know it's not correct yet.

Comment: What is ticking me off is that the "HARDER" sets (10, 11, and possibly 12) are easier than this puzzle. Sorry for being a little salty to you.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by **[Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45592/30633)**, this is a level from a game.

> It has a fairly easily searchable solution:  **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkEN8-k-Yx4**

I'm not sure there's any value in trying to describe the solution in any meaningful way.

> The video speaks for itself, and shows exactly what steps to take to complete the level.